# UIModalPresentationFullScreen - backgroundColor behind TransitionAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

I'm currently building a universal app.

After the user taps a button, I present some settings in a modal View in the following way:

```
viewCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
viewCtrl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];
```

On the iPhone and iPad both Transitionsstyles look the same. Now the problem is, on the iPad the background, behing the tilting view, is white. This white background just looks ugly.
On the iPhone it is black, as it is supposed to be.

I also tried adding a black backgroundview to my [UIApplication window]

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[window addSubview:bgView];
```

but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is as simple as setting the UIWindow background color to black.  For example, if you open the MainWindow.xib in IB, you should be able to set the background there - or in your AppDelegate you should be able to set the background of the UIWindow.

Comment: Thank you, of all the options I had, I ignored the easiest one :D